# PostSharp and uninitialized objects

Tags: postsharp

Assumed I have an aspect implementing `IInstanceScopedAspect` and I have this aspect applied to methods in a type. How can I initialize the aspects when creating the object with `FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject`? The constructor is not executed and therefore I get a `NullReferenceException` when I execute the method where the aspect is applied.

Is there a PostSharp API which can be used to initialize the object's aspects ?

Comment: I want my bounty back :D

Comment: Since PostSharp IL weaves.  I would build the code, then look at it with a decompiler (ILSpy).  This can give you an insight into what you are actually dealing with.

Comment: I actually know what I'm dealing with. The `InitializeAspects` method is not executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `InitializeCurrentAspects` method available for exactly this scenario, as documented here; http://doc.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp-2.0/Default.aspx##PostSharp-2.0.chm/html/M_PostSharp_Aspects_AspectUtilities_InitializeCurrentAspects.htm